g++: error: Downloads\programcodes\programTEST: No such file or directory
Getting an error of "g++: error: Downloads\programcodes\programTEST: No such file or directory
" upon running the codeenter image description here
Tried installing the extension for C++. install mingw. and im stuck now with this error

Please paste the text in the question instead of attaching images.  The problem is the space in the directory name.  If you really really really want a space in the directory name or filename, enclose the entire path in quotes.  No idea how to do this in VS Code, which you are using.
